# Trying to search through text on a website in PlayWright API

Tags: css, text, playwright, playwright-python

The text I'm searching for is all contained within a CSS class called "content-center", and within that is a series of CSS classes all with the same name that old similar, but different information. It seems to only be returning `[<JSHandle preview=JSHandle@node>]` rather than returning the text itself as if saying "yes, this text is on the page X times".

```
page.wait_for_selector('.content-center')
print(page.query_selector_all(".content-center:has-text('Bob Johnson')"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`page.query_selector_all` returns the [`ElementHandle[]`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-elementhandle) values of the elements which got found. Over these you can loop and call the `text_content()` method to get the text out of that specific element.

Also in most cases, its enough to use the text-selectors to verify something is on the page or an element has text, see [here](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/selectors#text-selector) for reference.